# Variable JS (Angular 8) acumula data de suscripción a servicio y no se reinicia

Tags: angular, typescript, http, ionic4

Estoy haciendo un sistema en Ionic 4(usa Angular 8) en el cual le envío un barrio y un producto/comercio/rubro a un servicio, y este me devuelve un array de objetos, donde cada objeto es un item encontrado de esa búsqueda hecha al principio. Luego muestro parte de esa info en un mapa. El problema venía cuando, al volver hacia atrás de la pantalla del mapa (imaginen una pantalla mobile que se sale por scroll right y se vuelve  mostrar la pantalla anterior, la Home) y volver a seleccionar otro producto/comercio/rubro y darle a buscar, el servicio me devolvía la variable anterior y le pusheaba los nuevos items encontrados.

Yo no entiendo realmente por qué tiene este comportamiento, si al comienzo del servicio, la variable (llamada this.business) la re-inicializo a "[ ]".

Estuve leyendo en foros que una vez que se cargó la page, ésta no vuelve a cargarse, y puede ser por esto que no me estaba tomando la inicialización de la variable.

Igualmente me resultó hipwr raro que sume los datos, y no los reemplace.

¿Eso es algo que ocurre al hacer subscribe a un servicio? ¿La variable no se actualiza, sino que se le suman datos?

No entiendo la lógica que usa, y por eso se me hubo complicado.

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: podrías considerar agregar código a tu explicación para que quede claro tu problema

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo leer el [tour] para conseguir tu primera medalla y comprender por qué es necesario aportar código (idealmente un [mcve]) para que te podamos ayudar